How to return a solved math problem within a defined return?
I am trying to get a (very) basic understanding of Python and its functions, and I found a way that it returns the text I want it to when used later within the script, but I cannot seem to have it output the solution to the math problem within the code and just the equation.
The code I am using is this:
def YearTime():
    return "Minutes in a year: (60*24)*365 "

YT = YearTime()

print(YT, "!", "Hello 2024!")

What I want it to output is
"Minutes in a year: 525600 ! Hello 2024!

but it just outputs
Minutes in a year: (60*24)*365  ! Hello 2024!


use https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

There are numerous ways to do this, including a simple f-string, but you do need to learn the difference between string expressions and arithmetic expressions and I fear an f-string will just blur the distinctions in your mind.

I think, it's simpler to think of it as 2 separate steps. STEP 1, compute the value of (60*24)*365 and store that in a variable, say result. STEP 2, figure out how to format a string with the result variable value. STEP 2 would lead you to the How do I put a variable’s value inside a string? These 2 steps are not just for solving math problems, but applies as well to any kind of values you want to put into a string.

Helpful or related Formatted string with calculated values in Python

You must use an f string. Here is how you should do it.
def YearTime():
    return f"Minutes in a year: {(60*24)*365} "

YT = YearTime()

print(YT, "!", "Hello 2024!")

F string will evaluate the part that is wrapped in curly braces as standard python code. But do not include a lot of logic in it. But rather just simple evaluation.
